# customize wp_list_comments design

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am using  `wp_list_comments` function to list the comments in comment.php in my theme.
Please look at my design below. It is a little complex to style for me. I am using CSS to style the look.

[image]

In the comment lists, **"THISIS2NDREPLY"** comment is the reply of the **"SUBJECT"** comment. How can I add lines connecting **THISIS2NDREPLY** to **"SUBJECT"** comment as shown in the design?

## My CSS

/* CSS Document */

```
#comments {
    clear: both;
}
#comments .navigation {
    padding: 0 0 18px 0;
}
h3#comments-title,
h3#reply-title {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
h3#comments-title {
    padding: 24px 0;
}
.commentlist {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.commentlist li.comment {
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;*/
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0 0 24px 0;
    /*padding: 0 0 0 56px;*/padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    position: relative;
}
.commentlist li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
#comments .comment-body ul,
#comments .comment-body ol {
    margin-bottom: 18px;
}
#comments .comment-body p:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
#comments .comment-body blockquote p:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.commentlist ol {
    list-style: decimal;
}


.commentlist .avatar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 0; 
}
.comment-author {
}
.comment-author cite {
    color: #4F57FF;
    font-style: normal; font-size:16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.comment-author cite a{ color: #4F57FF; text-decoration:none;}
.comment-author .says {
    font-style: italic;
}
.comment-meta {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0 0 18px 0; margin: 0 0 5px 0; 
}
.comment-meta a:link,
.comment-meta a:visited {
    color: #545354;
    text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold;
}
.comment-meta a:active,
.comment-meta a:hover {
    color: #ff4b33;
}
.commentlist .even {
}
.commentlist .bypostauthor {
}
.reply {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0 0 0px 0; clear:both;
}
.reply a,
a.comment-edit-link {
    color: #888;
}
.reply a:hover,
a.comment-edit-link:hover {
    color: #ff4b33;
}
.commentlist .children {
    list-style: none; 
    margin: 0;
}
.commentlist .children li {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.commentlist ul.children{
    background: #fff url('images/cmt-thrd-L.gif') no-repeat 0px 0px; 
}

.commentlist .depth-1 {
    background: #fff url('images/cmt-thrd-vline.gif') repeat-y -38px 0; float:left;
}
.commentlist li.depth-2, .commentlist li.depth-3, .commentlist li.depth-4, .commentlist li.depth-5 {
    background: #fff url('images/cmt-thrd-vline.gif') repeat-y -38px 0; 
}
.commentlist li.depth-1{
    border-left:0px solid #C1C5FE;}
```

I don't know how to apply the link arrow to comments and reply. So please suggest me. How to do this.

Thanks

Comment: You can add the HTML structure to help understand how you are styling it.

Answer (score 0):

can you not apply a css background image like this:

```
.commentlist li ul li{
     background: url('path to image') no-repeat left top;
     padding-left:60px;
}
```

by the way, it is a very nice design